# Read permissions to list programatically

Tags: list

My scenario is I am having two lists X and Y . Of which both have broken inheritance and having unique permissions. Now i am trying to add new group to the list permissions and assign read only access to that group. How to follow to do so programatically. I am using SharePoint 2010. Till now i was succesfull to create groups to the list permissions. but unable to make group as read only to the list.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add new role definition to the list’s role assignments collection.

Here is the code to do that:

```
SPList list = …//your list
SPPrincipal principal = …//user or group;

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = new SPRoleDefinition();
roleDefinition = list.ParentWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Reader);
SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefinitionBindingCollection = new SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection();
roleDefinitionBindingCollection.Add(roleDefinition);
roleAssignment.ImportRoleDefinitionBindings(roleDefinitionBindingCollection);
list.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
list.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```